# Below UITextChecker Function Is Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

```
NSString * currentWord;
        currentWord = Text.text;
        UITextChecker* checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
        NSString* preferredLanguage = [[UITextChecker availableLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSRange range;
 range = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentWord
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentWord length])
                                            startingAt:0
                                                  wrap:NO
                                              language:preferredLanguage];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"Word found");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Word not found");
        }
```

//Here i used UITextChecker Function ,even for the wrong word, the above function shows correct word statement
eg: wrong word like abcd,
   bcde,
   cdef,
   CAPs, kindly help me what is the reason behind this. Is there any other option to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should give `[[UITextChecker availableLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` for getting english language. Can you pls try dat.

Comment: I change the object index to 0, its not working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    UITextChecker *Checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, inputWord.length);


    NSRange misspelledRange = [Checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:[Sentence lowercaseString] range:range startingAt:0 wrap:NO language:@"en_IN"];

    bool isValidWord = misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;

    //NSLog(@"----%i", misspelledRange.location);
    if (isValidWord)
    {
        isValidWord = [self checkIfWordExistsInSuggestedSpellings:Sentence];
        NSLog(@"++++%d", isValidWord);

    }

    return isValidWord;

}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Invalid word");
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNotFound
```

means that whatever you asked for wasn't found. `==` is equality operator. Your code prints "Word found" when `range.location` is equal to `NSNotFound`.